# How to force typescript to load .d.ts file containing [declare module ".someExtension"] from npm package (from node_modules directory)

Tags: typescript, vite, typescript-declarations, typescript-module-resolution

i'm developing a vite plugin which transforms imported modules with custom extensions and turns them into javascript code which export some data (objects specifically).
everything is working fine when i test the plugin. but the problem is that when i use this plugin in a project (trying to simulate the developer experience with the plugin), the files with this custom extension is not recognized by typescript, which is expected of course, so i get this error `Cannot find module './filename.someExtension' or its corresponding type declarations.`

to keep things simple, i will put here some simple (and fake) examples of what i did, so that the question be clear.

say i have a file with json-like format containing a list of users, and the file has `.users` extension.
as an example say this is the contents of the file:

```json
[
    {
        name: "john",
        age: 35,
        job: "software engineer",
    },
    // other users
]
```

and the plugin code looks like this:

```
import { promises as fs } from "fs";
import type { Plugin } from "vite";

const UsersPlugin: () => Plugin = () => {

  return {
    name: "users-plugin",
    enforce: "pre",
    async load(id) {
      if (id.endsWith(".users")) {
        const src = await fs.readFile(id, "utf-8");
        return { code: src };
      }
      return null;
    },
    async transform(src, id) {
      if (id.endsWith(".users")) {
        const users = JSON.parse(src)
        const code = `
        export users = ${users}
        `
        return {code};
      }
      return null;
    },
  };
};

export default UsersPlugin
```

and the developer (user of the plugin) would import the `.users` file as follows

```
import {users} from '/path/to/file.users'
```

and here where the problem shows up.
the developer will see squiggly line under the `'/path/to/file.users'` saying `Cannot find module '/path/to/file.users' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)`

what i have tried is to create a `users.d.ts` file in the root directory of my package so when the plugin is installed the `users.d.ts` file will be located at `node_modules/users.d.ts`

the content of `users.d.ts`:

```
declare module "*.users" {
  interface User {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    job: string;
  }
  const users: User[];
  export { users };
}
```

this didn't work but if the developer (user of the plugin) puts this file somewhere in his project where it gets detected by typescript it works, or if he/she adds the path to the file in `tsconfig.json` (`"include": ["node_modules/users-plugin/users.d.ts"]`) it also works.

i have also tried to add the file in `package.json` of the package like this:

```
"types": "./lib/index.d.ts",
"exports": {
    ...
    "./users": {
      "types": "./users.d.ts"
    },
    ...
},
"files": [
    "lib/**/*",
    "modules.d.ts"
],
```

(i saw something similar in the vite's code base itself for the client.d.ts file)
but it didn't work.
i tried also puting the `users.d.ts` file under the `lib` directory and add the `/// <reference types="./users" />` tag at the top of `index.d.ts` file, but none of these works.

what i want is, simply, when the user of my plugin installs the plugin from npm registry and adds it to his `vite.config.ts`'s `plugins` list, the imports of files with `.users` extension gets typed properly without the need of adding any extra config from the developer.
how can i achieve this ?